# How to vertical align an image inside li

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertical align my image in my li tag.

I have something like this.

```
<nav id='tabs-wrapper'>
  <ul id='tabs'>
    <li><a href='index.html'><img id='btn' src='images/home.png'/></a></li><img class='vert'              
         src='images/vert2.png'/>
    <li><a href='#'>Project</a></li><img class='vert' src='images/vert2.png'/>
    <li><a href='test2.html'>Test</a></li><img class='vert' src='images/vert2.png'/>
    <li><a href='#'>contact</a></li><img class='vert' src='images/vert2.png'/>
  </ul>
```

css

```
nav #tabs{
float: left;
height: 46px;
}

nav #tabs .vert{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

nav #tabs li{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 42px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:15px;
}

#tabs li:hover{
    border-bottom:1px solid blue;
    line-height:30px;
}

#tabs li a{
   margin: 0 10px;
   line-height: 48px;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

#btn{
line-height: 48px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

For some reason, the first li (contain an image) can't seem to vertical align to middle (the rest li works fine).

Can anyone help me about it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't have random images outside the `<li>` tags. That's not proper markup. Everything should be *inside* the `<li>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an unorderd list, anything outside of an `<li>` is invalid HTML (as wrapped in ### below).

```
<li><a href='index.html'><img id='btn' src='images/home.png'/></a></li>###<img class='vert'              
         src='images/vert2.png'/>###
```

If this image is part of the UI it belongs as a CSS background, not an inline image.

Use:

```
#tabs a {
     display:block;
     background:url(images/vert2.png);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-position:0px 0px;
     padding-left:30px; 
}
```

Adjust the padding and background-position to suit your layout.